# scala macro generic field of generic class not apply class generic type parameter

Tags: scala, generics, macros, scala-macros

Generic case class

```
case class GroupResult[T](
  group: String,
  reduction: Seq[T]
)
```

Macro method

```
 def foo[T] = macro fooImpl[T]

 def fooImpl[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context) = {
    import c.universe._
    val tpe = weakTypeOf[T]
     tpe.declarations.collect {
      case m: MethodSymbol if m.isCaseAccessor => println(m.returnType)
    }
    c.literalUnit
  }
```

When I invoke `foo[GroupResult[Int]]`

The output is

```
String
Seq[T]
```

T is not applied ? How can I get the applied `Seq[Int]` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `typeSignatureIn` to get the type signature of a method given `GroupResult[Int]`:

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.Context

case class GroupResult[T](group: String, reduction: Seq[T])

def foo[T] = macro fooImpl[T]

def fooImpl[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context) = {
  import c.universe._

  val tpe = weakTypeOf[T]

  tpe.declarations.collect {
    case m: MethodSymbol if m.isCaseAccessor => println(m.typeSignatureIn(tpe))
  }

  c.literalUnit
}
```

And then:

```
scala> foo[GroupResult[Int]]
=> String
=> Seq[Int]
```

So we're closer, but now we're getting the "types" of the accessors, not their return types. If we want the return types we can use the `NullaryMethodType` extractor:

```
def foo[T] = macro fooImpl[T]

def fooImpl[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context) = {
  import c.universe._

  val tpe = weakTypeOf[T]

  tpe.declarations.collect {
    case m: MethodSymbol if m.isCaseAccessor => m.typeSignatureIn(tpe) match {
      case NullaryMethodType(returnType) => println(returnType)
    }
  }

  c.literalUnit
}
```

And then:

```
scala> foo[GroupResult[Int]]
String
Seq[Int]
```

And we're done.

Comment: By the how did you know that ? Are there some comprehensive materials to learn such things ?

Comment: Unfortunately, we're not there yet with documentation. There are official overviews of reflection and macros at http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/, but they are somewhat lacking. There are several blog posts that cover implementation details (e.g. http://imranrashid.com/posts/scala-reflection/ or http://blog.echo.sh/post/65955606729/exploring-scala-macros-map-to-case-class-conversion, to name just a few), but to the best of my knowledge there's no comprehensive list of those. You could also take a look at our recent workshop: https://github.com/scalamacros/macrology201.